# SDK2: Re-ranking a portfolio object

Tags: rally

I'm trying to allow drag and drop re-ranking across two different grids.

This does not seem to be working in RC1 (though inside the same grid does work), so I am trying to do drag and drop ranking across grids myself.

That's seems fairly straightforward, I just add:

```
viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                  ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                  dragGroup: dd1,
                  dropGroup: dd2
            }
}
```

Now I can drag and drop across grids (albeit it does not exactly follow the Rally style guides).  Unfortunately, this alone does not save the results.  For that I need to define a drop listener:

```
            listeners: {
                  drop: function(node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
                      var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('ObjectID') : ' on empty view';

                      console.log('Dropped ' + data.records[0].get('ObjectID') + dropOn);

                }
              }
```

But how do I re-rank the dropped record?  By inspecting how rally operates on a normal backlog, it looks like there are "rankAbove" and "rankBelow" commands in the Rally WSAPI, but how would I call them in my drop function?  If I was just updating a regular field, I presume I could just call record.set(), but for ranking I need to make one of these special calls and given the record I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work wiring up drag'n'drop between grids! For ranking, you may wish to check out the [Rally.data.Ranker](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.Ranker) Singleton. It's defined as Private. It is used in the [Drag'n'Drop Ranking Plugin](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/DragDrop3.html#Rally-ui-grid-plugin-DragDrop) for [Rally.ui.grid.Grid](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid).

With the Ranker, you could implement something similar to the following sample (adjusted to your own environment, of course):

```
listeners: {
drop: function(node, dragData, droppedOnRec, dropPosition) {
    var draggedRec  = dragData.records[0];

    var dropOn = droppedOnRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + droppedOnRec.get('FormattedID') : ' on empty view';

    console.log('Dropped ' + draggedRec.get('FormattedID') + dropOn);

    if (draggedRec && droppedOnRec) {
        console.log("what is this?", this.title, this.releaseRef, dropPosition, droppedOnRec);

        draggedRec.set('Release', this.releaseRef);

        Rally.data.Ranker.rankRelative({
            recordToRank: draggedRec,
            relativeRecord: droppedOnRec,
            position: dropPosition,
            saveOptions: {
                callback: function() {console.log('saved');}
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('no drop', draggedRec, droppedOnRe, dropPosition);
    }
},
```

Comment: I got the code working and I've updated your solution somewhat-- thanks!  The one remaining problem is that the drag and drop icons seem to be messed up-- I think because they are still being over-ridden by the rally defaults for drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Unfortunately they got rejected by a few moderators before I had a chance to review... Maybe post them in a 2nd follow-on answer. Cheers.

Comment: Actually it looks like I can override the moderators and accept your edits. Done!